# How to add patterns or stripes to SSRS data cells instead of a color

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, cells

IN SSRS:
I can only add Solid color fills to the data cells inside a matrix.
How do I add Stripes or Patterns as background fill instead of a solid color.
Is there a particular color code like '#xxxx' for stripes?
There are certain rows in my report that need to have stripes or patterns as backgrou fill.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found some methods around this:

**1**- You can use image gradients to fill text boxes by right-clicking the cell and selecting text box properties. You can use the Fill tab to select a small image or item that has a gradient or pattern and apply it within your cell(s)/report.

**2** - Another approach is to use a combination of Font/Color/Bold/Italic/Underline and Boarder colors/weight to achieve your desired result.

**3** - Apply a gradient-style scheme to your report by using one or more colors and dynamically changing the hue as you go up or down the report. That way, the top could be darker than the bottom, or vis-versa.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Only the image option worked. Surprised that a major reporting tool doesnt have inbuilt options for stripes or bars. Importing an image (created in paint)with a stripe inside the cell  is a bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Numerous fonts can be used.

1. Open the Character Map
2. Select Arial in the Font drop down
3. Scroll to near the bottom, select the cross character
4. Hit the Select button a number of times, grab as many characters as the SSRS textbox may require to fill its width
5. Click copy
6. In SSRS select the textbox then Ctrl-P to paste
7. Experiment with font size and font color to get the desired effect
8. Setting padding to zero may help
9. Setting row CanGrow to False may help

I find there is a little gap between cells vertically but it is close to perfect for me. There is likely to be a character in Arial or another font that works even better.

[image]